# control must be defined as 'standalone' Value not setting to name attribute TypeScript ,Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am basically trying to assign a value to name, the type attribute of form but it's not getting assign and its giving standalone problem

```
<div *ngFor="let a of UserFormArray">
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sender(f)" name="FormName">
{{a.name}}
<input type={{a.type}} [name]=a.name ngModel #awda="ngModel" required>
Name:
<input name="FirstName" ngModel #FirstName="ngModel" required> LastName:
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Error: ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Comment: Try with `[attr.name]`

Comment: It should work if all of your `UserFormArray` items have `name` property

Comment: not working, [attr.name]

Comment: I tried to reproduce this earlier and only had an issue when `a.name` was empty, as @yurzui suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention the `name` attribute for form elements.

```
<div>
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sender(f)">

<input name="FirstName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="a" required> Firstname : {{FirstName.value}}
<br/>
<input name="LastName" #LastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="b" required> 
LastNme : {{LastName.value}}
<br>
<button>Submit</button>


</form>
</div>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvxuyw